# What is a "Port" in linker?

Tags: linker, llvm, lld

I'm reading the documentations of [LLD](http://lld.llvm.org/) (LLVM linker) and it mentioned "ports".

Eg.,

> The ELF **port** is the one that will be described in this document.
>   The PE/COFF **port** is complete, including Windows debug info (PDB)
>   support. The WebAssembly **port** is still a work in progress (See
>   WebAssembly lld port)

Can someone explain what exactly is a linker port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these context the part of the linker that actually writes the output files (in the respective formats like ELF for *nix and PE/COFF for Windows).

Since the formats (and associated debuginfo) can be quite complex, this can be quite a large, and because they are also somewhat platform dependent here it is referred to as a "port" (as in porting, carrying over software from one system to the other), because adding support for the various file formats is a/the major part of adding new target.